# Проблема с оптимизацией ORM в Kohana (SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `tablename`)

Tags: orm, kohana

Доброе время суток, форумчане.
У меня появилась проблема с запросом в одну таблицу БД:

```
$help1 = ORM::factory('help')
                    ->where('id', '=', '1');
```

При формировании 
запроса в таблицу, получается:

```
Model_help Object ([_table_name:protected] => helps …[last_query] => SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `helps`…
```

Один из вариантов решения данной проблемы нашел на [ссылка](http://blogocms.ru/2011/05/kohana-uskoryaem-orm/) (создал файл, положил в директорию «classes»), но опять в сформированном запросе получается какая-то чехарда:

```
Model_help Object([_table_name:protected] => helps…. [last_query] => SELECT `department`… FROM `departments`…
```

Т.е. у меня есть таблица «departments», но речь же не о ней.
Второй вариант [ссылка](http://habrahabr.ru/post/154865/), но он какой-то громоздкий, и предполагает вставку полученной структуры таблицы в модель вручную.

Может, есть еще какой-нибудь вариант? Можно, конечно, через "DB::select" попробовать, но привязался к ORM.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Konstantin78

У ORM нет иного пути получить структуру данных, кроме как запросить ее у БД. Даже если кэшировать результат, в один момент просто получится, что структура БД обновилась, а кэш - нет, при этом даже нельзя надеяться на ошибку со стороны БД, чтобы обновить кэш: если будет добавлен новый столбец со значением по умолчанию, то ORM о нем не узнает, пока кэш не дропнется.

Традиционный вопрос: вы что, уперлись в долгоиграющие запросы (от 0.3с хотя бы), чтобы вам потребовалась оптимизация?

> попробыть

?

Comment: Тогда, какой вариант?

Comment: @Konstantin78 Читайте, как создаются [модели в Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/orm/models) и как [ими пользоваться](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/orm/using)

Comment: @Konstantin78, еще раз: в том, что такой запрос выполняется, ошибки нет.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно забыл в конце запроса, добавить    "->find()"